# Xamarin Issue: The project App1 is missing Android SDKs

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

The project App1 is missing Android SDKs required for building. Double-click on this message and follow the prompts to install them.

I clicked on pop up bar, but didn't work anything.

What I am missing here?

[image: SDK is missing]

[image: SDKs are already installed]

[image: NDK and other library files are installed]

[image: Correct directory for Misc. files for Xamarin]

Comment: What is the Compile API Level of the project?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do but the simplest is this... under tools ->Xamarin -> Android Settings check the box as shown and save. Reload & Rebuild. Give it a few mins to install the package, it will work.

[image]