# New Xamarin.forms project giving missing android sdk error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I created a new Xamarin.forms project in Visual Studio 2019 and downloaded all of the required workloads. But as soon as I opened the project, I got an error saying:

The Project ProjectName is missing Android SDKs required for building. Double-click on this message and follow the prompts to install them.

Then, I clicked on it and accepted the Android SDK license, but no matter how many times I did, the error showed up.

I have not written any code yet, and I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443170/xamarin-issue-the-project-app1-is-missing-android-sdks), which doesn't work either.

EDIT: I found a workaround, but I needed Android Studio installed for it to work. Basically, I went to Tools-SDK Manager in Android Studio and downloaded the Android SDK from there. Then I copied the file path of the SDK and changed the SDK path in Visual Studio to the former path. That fixed the error.

Comment: What Android version are you building against and which version does Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager show as being already installed?

Comment: after you install the android sdk,you may need to restart Visual Studio for this change to take effect

Comment: @MouseOnMars I'm using API 28 and I installed API 28 from the SDK Manager.       I restarted Visual studio and also tried creating a new project, and nothing helped.

Comment: I had quite a few build issues with new solutions myself. Try going to the individual project folders and delete every bin & obj folder. Then restore all the nuget packages in Visual Studio (right click on your solution in the solution explorer and click "Restore Nuget Packages") and try to rebuild your solution